# SQL query using CASE to group data into time intervals

Tags: sql

I am totally new to SQL and am trying to do some on-the-job training exercises which are currently kicking my rear end.

I am trying to write a query that will look at a table column containing minutes called CC_To_Dep and measure that column against some buckets: 0-30Mins, 30-60Mins, 1-2Hrs, Over 2 Hrs and then return the data to look something like this

`Case Count    Time
 698,523        0-30 Mins
 235,888        30-60 Mins
 50,853         1-2 Hrs
 2,855          Over 2 Hrs`

This is what I am using and it labels each record with the time buckets above but it doesn't group them together. I tried a GROUP BY clause at the end but it but then the whole thing errored out.

```
SELECT 
(CC_To_Dep) as CaseCount
,CASE 
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)< 30 THEN '0-30Mins'
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)>= 30 AND (CC_To_Dep)<= 60 THEN '30-60Mins'
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)> 60 AND (CC_To_Dep)<= 120 THEN '1-2Hrs'
ELSE 'Over 2 Hrs'
END as Time
FROM Table1
WHERE YEAR(Arr_date)=2013
```

Any help is appreciated. I have looked around for answers but it is really hard for me to read code in other examples and then apply it to my situation. I'll get there one day but today is not that day.

Comment: What's the data type of CC_TO_DEP. Which db server are you using

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)< 30 THEN '0-30Mins'
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)>= 30 AND (CC_To_Dep)<= 60 THEN '30-60Mins'
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)> 60 AND (CC_To_Dep)<= 120 THEN '1-2Hrs'
ELSE 'Over 2 Hrs'
END as Time
, count(*) as caseCount
FROM Table1
WHERE YEAR(Arr_date)=2013
group by 
CASE 
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)< 30 THEN '0-30Mins'
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)>= 30 AND (CC_To_Dep)<= 60 THEN '30-60Mins'
WHEN(CC_To_Dep)> 60 AND (CC_To_Dep)<= 120 THEN '1-2Hrs'
ELSE 'Over 2 Hrs'
END
```